# External event dropped doesn't appear on FullCalendar ResourceViews

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

Recently, I've tried to use a fork of FullCalendar, called "FullCalendar ResourceViews" (http://tux.fi/~jarnok/fullcalendar-resourceviews/) with success. But I've encountered a problem. In fact, when I drag External Events into fullCalendar on the tabs resourceWeek, resourceNextWeeks, and resourceMonth, event doesn't appear on resourceDay tab!

However, when I drop event on resourceDay tab, event appears correctly on all tabs (resourceDay, resourceWeek, resourceNextWeeks and resourceMonth).

Is it a bug of this plugin? Have you got an idea to resolve this problem?

Best regards,

JohnDoe66

Answer (score 0):

Append more information to event object inside the drop callback, like:

```
copiedEventObject.allDay = false;
copiedEventObject.resource = arguments[4].id;
```

Comment: Please indent code 4 spaces when posting answers.  The easiest way to do this, is to highlight all of the code and press the `{ }` button above the editor.